# setting specific values of a signal to zero

Tags: matlab

i have a signal and i want to set the values that are less than a specific point to zero (in my example the value is 0.005), i know it's similar to the filtering process but i want to clean the signal from the static noise completely, so my code is :

```
close all;clear all;clc;
sig=audioread('sp1.mp3');
N=length(sig);
n_sig=zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N

    n_sig= sig((sig>0.005)); %the new signal

end
```

The problem is that it creates an infinity loop and i have to stop the code manually, also it gives me only the positive values, but i want also the negative that are smaller than -0.005, any ideas how to modify my code? thanks in advance.

Comment: The "for" loop you used, what is it for?

Comment: Forget the for loop: `n_sig=sig ; n_sig(abs(n_sig)<0.005)=0 ;`

Comment: well the for loop was to search for every element of the signal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a an array `A` and want to set some specific values to zero do:

```
A=rand(100,1)-0.5; % example array

A(abs(A)<0.005)=0
```

If you want create a new array without those values, do

```
B=A(abs(A)>0.005);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use boolean indexing and absolute value:

```
sig(abs(sig) < 0.005) = 0;
```

This modifies the signal in-place. If you don't want to modify the original vector, just copy it and do this in-place thing on the copy.